# Big-O complexity of iterating over every substring

Tags: computational-complexity

What is the Big-O complexity of iterating over every possible non-empty substring of a string of length $N$?

The simple way to do the iteration over string $S$ is:

```
for i in 1 .. N:
    for j in (i+1) .. N:
        S[i .. j]
```

Clearly this is more complex than $\mathcal{O}\left(N\right)$ but less complex than $\mathcal{O}\left(N^2\right)$, but I'm not sure how to understand the complexity of these nested loops.

Comment: You have $\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ iterations

Comment: @Tryss: Thanks, would you be able to explain this a little? In fact, I actually need to add a third nested loop, which iterates j/2 times, so I'm not sure how to extrapolate from your answer to a more general solution.

Comment: Your inside loop do N-i iterations, so the total number of iterations is given by $$\sum_{i=0}^N N-i = \sum_{i=0}^N i = \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$ This is a classical formula, and there exist similar formula (but more complex) for $\sum_{i=0}^{N} i^n$. Actually $\sum_{i=0}^{N} i^n$ is a n-th degree polynomial

Answer (score 2):

$$
S = (1+ 1+ \ldots 1) + //\text {n times}\\
  (1+1+ \ldots 1) +  //\text{n-1 times} \\
  \ldots 1
$$
Hence $S = 1 + 2 + \ldots (n-1) +n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$